# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "estar pez"?

Tags: etimología, modismos, expresiones, historia, animales

[**Estar** alguien **pez** en alguna materia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SqyV2F4) viene definido como

> 1. loc. verb. coloq. **Ignorarla por completo**.

Aparece en el DRAE por primera vez en la edición de 1970, pero ¿se sabe de dónde viene y cuándo empezó a utilizarse?

Answer (score 4):

Parece que viene de algo como «estar más mudo que un pez»:

> **Estar pez!** La palma de la mano derecha se coloca sobre el dorso de la izquierda. Ambos pulgares imitan el movimiento de unas aletas de pez. Interpretación: **Estuve más mudo que un pez, es decir, que no supe decir una palabra en el examen.** El gesto insinúa además la idea de «nadando», la que por asociación fonética se trueca, resultando «nada».
>
> - [*Ensayos y Estudios*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Wf1DAAAAIAAJ&q=%22estar+pez%22) (1939)

---

Sin embargo, este sitio conjetura que la frase viene de la otra significación de [*pez*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SqzysER) (del Lat. *picis*, no de *piscis*):

> En esta expresión, *pez* se refiere a la sustancia resinosa, sólida, lustrosa, quebradiza y de color pardo amarillento que se obtiene echando en agua fría el residuo que deja la trementina al acabar de sacarle el aguarrás.
>
> Esta pez se utiliza para lustrar y proteger pieles curtidas, así como para revestir el interior de odres y botas de vino. Con este recubrimiento se les hace impermeables además de mejorar su conservación. Por eso se utiliza esta expresión para personas que están vacías como un odre, sin nada dentro. Ignorantes por completo.
>
> - https://lalenguaesagrandesconocida.wordpress.com/2014/10/12/estar-pez-en/

Parece que el autor pensaba que podría ser una contracción de *[estar] '[pez con pez](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SqzysER)'* (que utiliza esta definición de *pez*), que es una frase [más antigua](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=JimQKEPdw3cC&pg=PA316&dq=%22pez+con+pez%22):

> #### [pe̲z̲ con pe̲z̲](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SqzysER)
>
> 1. `loc. adv.` Totalmente desocupado, desembarazado o vacío, por alusión a lo que sucede en los pellejos empegados cuando no tienen nada dentro.

---

<sup>Cita más temprano que encontré:</sup>

> <sup>... á Perencejo, que se sabe de buten las papeletas N y M, **y está pez** en las R y S, le tocan las primeras al examinarse en la Academia de Artillería y las segundas en la de Administración Militar, Perencejito será artillero; mas si la ciega suerte ...</sup>
>
> - <sup>[*La España moderna*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=tfMaAAAAYAAJ&q=%22est%C3%A1+pez%22) (1904)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

¿De dónde viene la expresión "estar pez"?

---

Normalmente se entiende como;

"*Saber muy poco o nada, sobre un asunto, especialmente en una asignatura escolar*".

---

**Si tuviera que resumir**, **tendría que decir que

"Estar pez", es la síntesis abreviada de una pequeña historia**.

De esa historia, que tiene varias versiones y que socialmente, tuvo que ser muy popular, proceden dos expresiones con significado idéntico en su origen, "**vagar, soltar alguna cosa libre y sin orden, no saber de lo que se esta hablando**".

Estas expresiones son;

- *Estar Pez*
- *Tampoco el Congrio es mal ave*."

(En su versión original, ambas se referían *a no saber de un asunto, desconocer un tema ó de lo que se esta hablando*. Actualmente, también ambas han evolucionado y poseen otras connotaciones más especificas, como se ha podido comprobar más arriba en lo que se entiende hoy en día por "estar pez").

---

La referencia más antigua a esta historia la he encontrado en la Argentina de 1918, en una revista que recoge de pasada esta vinculación, y ya en los años veinte del siglo pasado, aparece desarrollada en distintas versiones y sentidos en España.

Mientras que en el lado Argentino se habla de un necio y el congrio, en el lado Español la comparación que se hace, con el Ave, se construye con el congrio y un nuevo rico, en la mejor interpretación encontrada. Así que intuyo, en principio, que "Estar Pez" es la versión Argentina, que se refiere al Congrio y "Tampoco el Congrio es mal ave", es el resumen ó versión Española de la misma historia.

---

Otras expresiones que vienen de historias.

Coloquialmente decimos "*Irse por los Cerros de Ubeda*", "*Salir por los Cerros de Ubeda*", cuando alguien se va por las ramas, relaciona cosas que no tienen nada que ver, divaga o se aleja del tema principal de la conversación que se esta tratando.

Sin embargo "Irse por los Cerros de Ubeda", es el resumen de una historia, en sus diferentes versiones, que procede de una anécdota, una vez conquistada la ciudad de Ubeda, por el Rey Fernando III el Santo en 1233.

---

De las versiones encontradas de la historia del Congrio que desconocen su procedencia destacar;

- Aquella que se interpreta simplemente como una salida u ocurrencia para llamar la atención ó un sin sentido, para estos ahí residiría la gracia.
- Aquellos que la interpretan como una forma de decir algo sin querer decir nada.
- Como pieza sabrosa a pesar de su origen humilde.
- Otros la hacen proceder, según ellos, de la frase que Eduardo Dato, ministro de Justicia, de Estado, de Marina, de Gobernación y varias veces presidente del Consejo de Ministros nacido en La Coruña en 1856 y asesinado por anarquistas en Marzo de 1921 pronuncio en un homenaje poco antes de su muerte, y por ser Semana Santa se cambio el plato de Faisán por el Congrio, pronunciando la celebre frase, «Tampoco el congrio es mal ave». Aunque esto no tiene sentido, ya que Eduardo Dato murió el 8 de Marzo de 1921 y la Semana Santa de ese año fue del 20 al 27 de Marzo y por otro lado estos desconocían que el dicho ya era popular en 1918.
- Por último, aparece una historia firmada por un tal Rigel en El Heraldo de Madrid de 1921, que tiene su mejor interpretación hasta ahora y que cuenta la anécdota de un nuevo rico, (el necio, en la versión Argentina), comiendo en un banquete.

  "*Un deslenguado me contó no ha mucho que en cierto banquete, al que asistía uno de estos hombres bárbaramente enriquecidos, sirvieron un plato de faisán sabrosamente condimentado, del cual se comió una buena ración el hombre de los muchos millones*.

  *Gran parecido encontraba el Creso del nuevo cuño la sazonada carne a la del pollo; pero ni por semejas podía confundirla con ella, y como pensaba regalarse en lo sucesivo con análoga pitanza, y no sabía su nombre, se atrevió a preguntárselo al comensal que estaba a su lado derecho*:

  — *Dígame usted, y perdone: ¿Cómo se llama esto que comemos?*

  — *Ave — dijo, mostrando extrañeza, el preguntado*.

  *Y aquí entra lo único censurable que podemos advertir en la conducta de crematístico insigne. El prurito de mostrarse enterado de todo apareció a sus ojos con gesto tentador y al punto en que comenzaba a comer del siguiente plato, que él conocía muy bien por ser de Congrio guisado, dijo el ricachón, inclinándose al oído de su vecino de la izquierda*:

  —¡*Tampoco es mal Ave el Congrio*! "

Así pues, esta misma historia, con sus variantes, se ha bifurcado en dos expresiones;

- "*estar pez*"
- "*tampoco el Congrio es mal ave*"

Y de esta manera, tanto las expresiones "*estar pez*", como "*tampoco el Congrio es mal ave*", son expresiones que originalmente venían a significar lo mismo, es decir, **a no saber de un asunto, desconocer un tema ó de lo que se esta hablando**.

Ambas expresiones han evolucionado;

Por un lado, "estar pez", es más ó menos estar mudo, desconocer e ignorar totalmente aquello de lo que se le esta hablando o le preguntan a la persona, extendiéndose singularmente hacia el mundo académico.

Por otro, "*tampoco el Congrio es un mal Ave*", ya al final de la década de 1os años veinte del siglo pasado, 1929, aparece con otro sentido, interpretado como aquel otro dicho, "A falta de pan buenas son tortas", en el sentido de si no tenemos aquello que es autentico, tampoco esta nada mal quedarse con la variante.

El Congrio, como pez, en si mismo también aparece entre otros como;

- Insulto, persona inútil, imbécil. (Halma, Benito Pérez Galdós)
- Forma de llamar fea a una mujer
- Nombre en la comedia clásica para uno de los cocineros (Plauto)

PD. No se refiere ni mucho menos a la sustancia resinosa, ni a palabras u otras expresiones de ese tipo ó contenido.